# Hello how do I insert API response into my MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, api

Hi I'm trying to insert  API response into my MySQL database.  i have converted the data into json format and I'm passing the data to mysql db using the code below each time I try to run the code 0 are inserted to mydb instead of real values

```
   <?php
class MagnusBilling
{
    protected $api_key;
    protected $api_secret;
    public $public_url;
    public $filter = [];
    public $result = [];
    public function __construct($api_key, $api_secret)
    {
        $this->api_key    = $api_key;
        $this->api_secret = $api_secret;
    }

    public function query(array $req = array())
    {

        // API settings
        $key         = $this->api_key;
        $secret      = $this->api_secret;
        $trading_url = $this->public_url;

        $module = $req['module'];
        $action = $req['action'];

        // generate a nonce to avoid problems with 32bit systems
        $mt           = explode(' ', microtime());
        $req['nonce'] = $mt[1] . substr($mt[0], 2, 6);

        // generate the POST data string
        $post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');
        $sign      = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $secret);

        // generate the extra headers
        $headers = array(
            'Key: ' . $key,
            'Sign: ' . $sign,



        );


        static $ch = null;
        if (is_null($ch)) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt(
                $ch,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
                'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MagnusBilling PHP bot; ' . php_uname('a') . '; PHP/' . phpversion() . ')'
            );
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trading_url . '/index.php/' . $module . '/' . $action);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // run the query
        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($res === false) {
            throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        $dec = json_decode($res, true);
        if (!$dec) {
            print_r($res);
            exit;
        } else {
            return $dec;
        }
    }

    public function create($module, $data = [])
    {
        $data['module'] = $module;
        $data['action'] = 'save';
        $data['id']     = 0;

        return $this->query($data);
    }

    public function update($module, $id, $data)
    {
        $data['module'] = $module;
        $data['action'] = 'save';
        $data['id']     = $id;

        return $this->query($data);
    }

    public function destroy($module, $id)
    {
        return $this->query(
            array(
                'module' => $module,
                'action' => 'destroy',
                'id'     => $id,
            )
        );
    }
    public function read($module, $page = 1, $action = 'read')
    {

        return $this->query(
            array(
                'module' => $module,
                'action' => $action,
                'page'   => $page,
                'start'  => $page == 1 ? 0 : ($page - 1) * 25,
                'limit'  => 25,
                'filter' => json_encode($this->filter),
                'filter' => json_encode($this->result),

            )
        );
    }

    public function buyDID($id_did, $id_user)
    {

        return $this->query(
            array(
                'module'  => 'did',
                'action'  => 'buy',
                'id'      => $id_did,
                'id_user' => $id_user,
            )
        );
    }

    public function getFields($module)
    {
        return $this->query(
            array(
                'module'    => $module,
                'getFields' => 1,
            )
        );
    }

    public function createUser($data)
    {
        $data['createUser'] = 1;
        $data['id']         = 0;

        return $this->query($data);
    }

    public function getModules()
    {
        return $this->query(
            array(
                'getModules' => 1,
            )
        );
    }

    public function getMenu($username)
    {
        return $this->query(
            array(
                'username' => $username,
                'getMenu'  => 1,
            )
        );
    }

    public function getId($module, $filed, $value)
    {

        $this->setFilter($filed, $value, 'eq');

        $query = $this->query([
            'module' => $module,
            'action' => 'read',
            'page'   => 1,
            'start'  => 0,
            'limit'  => 1,
            'filter' => json_encode($this->filter),
        ]);

        $this->filter = [];

        if (isset($query['rows'][0])) {
            return $query['rows'][0]['id'];
        }
    }

    public function clearFilter()
    {
        $this->filter = [];
    }

    public function setFilter($field, $value, $comparison = 'st', $type = 'string')
    {
        $this->filter[] = (object) [
            'type'       => $type,
            'field'      => $field,
            'value'      => $value,
            'comparison' => $comparison,
        ];
    }
}


$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "api");
$magnusBilling             = new MagnusBilling('92b1c021402efd293fd4b3fd0', ' 1178f001b001e29c9b7a15a1f');
$magnusBilling->public_url = "http://voip/mbilling"; // Your MagnusBilling URL




$result = $magnusBilling->read('callerid');

      
            // Convert the JSON String into PHP Array
            $array = json_decode($result, true); 
            
            // Extracting row by row
            foreach($array as $row) {
  
                // Database query to insert data 
                // into database Make Multiple 
                // Insert Query 
                $query .= 
                "INSERT INTO account VALUES 
                ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["cid"]."', 
                '".$row["name"]."'); "; 
               
                $table_data .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["cid"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                </tr>
                '; // Data for display on Web page
            }



  
            if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query)) {
                echo '<h3>Inserted JSON Data</h3><br />';
                echo '
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th width="45%">id</th>
                    <th width="10%">cid</th>
                    <th width="45%">name</th>
                </tr>
                ';
                echo $table_data;  
                echo '</table>';
            }
          ?>
```

this is the response am trying to insert into mysql db

- { "rows": [ { "id": "1", "cid": "25411188205", "name": "Nairobi
  Muslim Academy", "description": "", "id_user": "3", "activated": "1",
  "idUserusername": "67800" } ], "count": "1", "sum": false }

Answer (score 0):

In your case your `$result` is {"rows":....}, so you should not use `foreach($array ...)`, you should use `foreach($array['rows'] as $row)` instead.